# gnome-terminal issue related to tty configuration

Tags: terminal, stty

I'm facing an strange issue, I'll add a photo since is better to explain what's happening

[image: tty issue in gnome-terminal]

As you can see. After using `git log` and exit (either pressing q or Q or :q or ^C), I'm not able to use more commands.

After googling a bit I came to the `stty sane` command, which seems to fix my terminal. But I can't tell *why* or *how* does it fix gnome-terminal.

As far as I can see, before and after fixing it `stty -a` shows the same output.

Any idea or suggestion about how to start debugging it?

I'm using gnome terminal for GNOME 3.22.2 using version 0.46.2 from VTE +GNUTLS

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer I took a second look to both configurations and I can see these differences

```
chris@Gentoo ~ $ diff stty-bad stty-good 
4c4
< werase = ^W; lnext = <undef>; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
---
> werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
6c6
< -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl 
ixon -ixoff
---
> -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl 
ixon -ixoff
9c9
< isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -
tostop -echoprt
---
> isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop 
-echoprt
```

This still is a long list to check, I'll read as much as I can from those options, but that leaves the answer... *how* does `stty sane` fix the problem and *what* is causing it, since `git log` is not the real problem. I tried with `git --no-pager log` and after a while printing commits, I press ^C and the same happens...

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, after switching each option the root seems to be the `-echo` variable. But that leaves me just one question. ***Why*** does `git log` or `^C` change the default `echo` variable. *Where* could I find the root? is it git? less (git log's pager)? or gnome-terminal? or even stty?

Answer (score 1):

That is, `git log` isn't cleaning up properly...  Applications that wait for single keys (such as vi, less) put the terminal into a mode that suppresses echo, eliminates special control characters, etc., just to make it simple.  But if they do not cleanup, that leaves the terminal unusable.

The `stty sane` command simply sets the terminal modes to a predetermined value.  If your editing-characters don't work, that fixes it (except for some Unix platforms where `stty sane` sets the erase character to `@`, etc).  I use a script for comparing `stty` output, but it's not short...

Your photograph has at least one difference (I see **`-icanon`**, which would be enough to interfere with line-editing).  For reference, here's what I see after `stty sane`:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

You might want to look closer, just in case.

Comment: I guess a followup question is why the shell lets programs change settings in the outer envorment - that is, why it doesn't revert changes programs make when they are not in the foreground.